# Loading a new page on changing select value in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a select tag which loads 10 shops. 
Shop Number should be passed as a parameter on changing the select value..
I tried to put a tag in my html like this..

```
<a href='#' id='wo_selected_shop'>aaa</a>
```

and in my script

```
$("#wo_select_shop").change(function() { 
    var shop_number = $("#wo_select_shop").val();
    var url = '/estimate_lookups/select_store?shop_number='+shop_number;
    $('#wo_selected_shop').attr('href',url).trigger('click');
});

$('#wo_selected_shop').click(function() {
    console.log("A Click"); 
});
```

Thing is on changing the select tag the console works and also the href is changing in console.. But url is not changing or the page is not changing.. But it changes if i click that a tag manually.. 
What do i miss?

Comment: for that `select_store` method in your controller there should be a `js.erb` file. Can you show this one?

Comment: And it is not the valid ajax request.

Comment: @Emu i tried ajax method.. THign is im not getting the page refreshed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you're doing is pretty complicated.
I've simplified this code a little for you.
Instead of triggering a click, use **window.open** function.
Hope it helps, here's the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/awesomestvi/ED7Tq/)

**HTML:**

```
<select id='wo_select_shop'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#wo_select_shop").change(function() { 
    var shop_number = $("#wo_select_shop").val();
    var url = '/estimate_lookups/select_store?shop_number='+shop_number;
    window.open(url);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to `awesomestvi`'s answer, you'll need to consider the role of **Turbolinks** in binding the `change` event to the select element:

```
$(document).on("change", "#wo_select_shop", function() { 
    var shop_number = $("#wo_select_shop").val();
    var url = '/estimate_lookups/select_store?shop_number='+shop_number;
    //awesomestvi's code here
});
```

One of the issues you'll have is Turbolinks will often prevent the `JS` binding to take place when you load a new page. Admittedly, this will only take place if you click a `turbolinks`-enabled link, but it may be an issue for you here, especially if you're loading the `select` box on a page from a link

To get around the `Turbolinks` issue, you'll be best binding the `change` event handler to the `document` object (which never changes), and [`delegating`](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to your select box

Comment: Agree with that... :)